# SQL Replace Typed XML Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm working with third-party software that stores an XML document of parameters as a column. I'm trying to write a SQL-Server script that will replace the email address in the XML below.

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"> 
  <KeyValueOfstringanyType> 
    <Key>Email</Key>
    <Value xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d3p1:string">Michael@dundermifflin.com</Value>
</KeyValueOfstringanyType>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType>
```

So far, the closest I've gotten is this... It runs and says rows were affected but does nothing.

```
update t 
set XMLColumn.modify('replace value of (/ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType/KeyValueOfstringanyType/Key/Value/string())[1] with "dwight@staples.com"')
```

After reviewing other posts and Microsoft's documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml?view=sql-server-ver15#a-replacing-values-in-an-xml-instance --Item D), it seems I'm missing something regarding the namespaces. If I understand the XML correctly, it appears that there are multiple namespaces to declare. After several attempts with no luck, my lack of XML experience has me turning here.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution.

As you correctly guessed, the culprit was a default namespace.

Also, I had to adjust the XPath expression.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, XMLColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (XMLColumn) VALUES
(N'<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <KeyValueOfstringanyType>
        <Key>Email</Key>
        <Value xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               i:type="d3p1:string">Michael@dundermifflin.com</Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringanyType>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays')
UPDATE @tbl 
SET XMLColumn.modify('replace value of (/ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType/KeyValueOfstringanyType/Value/text())[1] with "dwight@staples.com"');

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: @Ray, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You muse declare default namespace

```
DECLARE @XML XML = N'<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"> 
  <KeyValueOfstringanyType> 
    <Key>Email</Key>
    <Value xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d3p1:string">Michael@dundermifflin.com</Value>
</KeyValueOfstringanyType>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType> '

set @XML.modify('
declare default element namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"; 
replace value of (/ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType/KeyValueOfstringanyType/Value/text())[1] with "dwight@staples.com"')

SELECT @XML
```